# Wordpress - add theme support

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type called banners and want to enable the thumbnails in that post type. Hence I have put the following code just after the starting tag on my functions file but the banners post type still are not showing featured image option in the admin panel.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'banner' ) );
}
```

If I replace the banner with post or page the featured image option does show up in the respective menu options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your custom post type allows the use of the featured image. Here is an example of a custom post type with thumbnails allowed:

```
<?php
function your_custom_post_types() {
    // Portfolio
    $labels_portfolio = array(
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'portfolio'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add Portfolio Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Post'),
        'menu_name' => __('Portfolio'),
        'name' => __('Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'singular_name' => __('Portfolio Post', 'post type singular name'),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
    );
    $args_portfolio = array(
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels_portfolio,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portfolio', 'with_front' => true ),
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'supports' => array( 'comments', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'title' ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'portfolio', $args_portfolio );
}
?>
```

**The line that allows the thumbnail is this one:**

```
'supports' => array( 'comments', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'title'
```